# Select and count how many rows

Tags: c#, sql, database

Sorry, I'm just learning C#. I'm use to HTML/PHP then actual programming.

I'm looking to use SQL SELECT to view data from search result however it's likely that because of multiple LIKE it may bring multiple rows (which I want) however if it brings multiple rows instead of selecting the first row to display I want a IF message stating that there is more than one row matching the criteria. Below is my current code (I have removed some code from it after **if (recordfound)** to shorten the code for this question)

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@Settings.Default.database);
con1.Open();
string qu = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE road LIKE '%" + inclocroad.Text.Trim() + "%' OR postcode LIKE '%" + inclocroad.Text.Trim() + "%' OR full_address LIKE '%" + inclocroad.Text.Trim() + "%' OR Property LIKE '%" + inclocno.Text.Trim() + "%' OR full_address2 LIKE '%" + inclocroad.Text.Trim() + "%' ";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qu, con1);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
bool recordfound = dr.Read();
if (recordfound)
{
    //Displays data from row
} 
else
{
    messagebox.show("No data found");
}
```

**Example**

User clicks button

SQL uses SELECT QUERY where the user has written the search result

IF SELECT QUERY has more than 1 row then display message box

Otherwise show the only row matching the search result.

Comment: Be aware of [SQL Injections](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm aware of the SQL injections however I have a prevention with a server checking each thing someone does and kicking them off the application if a SQL injection is detected which works well. It's a private application anyway so i'm not really fussed by it.

Comment: My textbox doesn't allow anything other than text and numbers.

Comment: instead of using DataTables I prefer to deal with objects, a simple ORM can do the trick. Like Dapper, from our friends here at stackoverflow https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you just count them:

`SELECT COUNT(1) ...`.

Since we are talking about just few rows it doesn't hurt performance or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you are hoping to load data using DataTable.

```
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qu, con1);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    bool recordfound = dr.Read();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (recordfound)
    {
         dt.Load(reader);
    } 
    
    int numRows= dt.Rows.Count;
    if(numRows > 1){
        messagebox.show("Data found"+ numRows);
    }
    else
    {
        messagebox.show("No data found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple... I just was having a moment.

I've made two SQL's with a IF query if it held more results or not.
The first SQL being a COUNT using ExecuteScalar than using a IF statement if it did hold more than one record.

Thanks for the help.